# Can the C++ struct aggregate initialisation be used to create temporary instance?

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, initialization

To quickly initialise small structs I often use the aggregate initialisation to keep the code small and simple:

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
Foo temp = {1, 2, 3};
```

I would assume this should also work to create a temporary instance which can be passed as function argument:

```
void myFunc(Foo foo) {
    // ...
}
```

**Is this possible? How is the exact syntax to use this feature?**

```
myFunc({1, 2, 3}); // ???
myFunc(Foo {1, 2, 3}); // ???
```

Comment: What did you experience when you tried it?

Comment: @KerrekSB I tried many expected variants but always got compiler errors. So I am not sure if just the compiler does not support it, or I do something wrong.

Comment: @KerrekSB I expect pain :)

Comment: what compiler errors did you get?

Comment: @tobi303 I get a syntax error. But I am using Visual Studio, so I did not expect much from the C++ implementation.

Comment: @Flovdis [So much](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7wd1177.aspx) for your Visual Studio comment.

Comment: @Wum This is interesting, I will investigate this in detail. Thank you for the link.

Comment: @Wum I am using Visual Studio 2012, it seems this is not implemented in this version of the compiler. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 1st case is [copy-list-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) and pretty fine for your example.

> function( { arg1, arg2, ... } ) ; (7)
>
> 7) in a function call expression, with braced-init-list used as an argument and list-initialization initializes the function parameter

So for `myFunc({1, 2, 3});`, `myFunc` expects a `Foo`; then the braced-init-list `{1, 2, 3}` will be used to copy-list-initialize a temporary `Foo` and being passed to `myFunc` as the argument.

For `myFunc(Foo {1, 2, 3});`, a temporary `Foo` will be direct-list-initialized explicitly, then is passed to `myFunc` as the argument.

There are some subtle differences between direct-list-initialization and copy-list-initialization, e.g. `explicit` converting constructor is not considered for copy-list-initialization:

```
struct Foo {
    // explicit converting constructor
    explicit Foo(int, int, int) {}
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

void myFunc(Foo foo) {
    // ...
}

myFunc({1, 2, 3});      // fail, can't convert from braced-init-list to Foo
myFunc(Foo {1, 2, 3});  // fine
```

Answer (score 1):

This small program compiled for me:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

void bar(const Foo&) {}


int main() {
    bar({1,2,3});
    bar(Foo{1,2,3});
}
```

The first call is implicit, the second is explicit; both work. If you have a template function or something where implicit conversion does not occur easily then you should use the second form.

Live example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13c9fb9e277be697

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `myFunc({1, 2, 3});`.